# Three electron in a potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am a little confused about the ground state energy of a system consisting of three electrons in a infinity potential well.

It seems that the energy is given by $2E_1 + E_2$, where $E_n = \alpha n^2$. But i can't understand why!

I mean, the wavefunction need to be totally antissymetric. This means that either the spatial wavefunction is symmetric while the spin wavefunction is antisymetric, or otherwise.

But, we can't form a spatial wavefunction with 2 eletrons in $n=1$ (say the potential goes from x=0 to x=a) and one in $n=2$ that be totally symmetric or antisymmetric!

Comment: Do you know about Slater determinants?

Comment: Note that the ground state here is degenerate because the electron in the $n=2$ level can have either spin up or spin down with the same energy. Maybe this causes some confusion?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yes, i do know it. The fact electron's spin is 1/2 is not the reason of confusion. The problem i am have is about the wavefunction itself! Suppose, so, we have two eletron ate $n=1$ and one at $n=2$, what would be the possible wavefunctions?

Answer (score 0):

There are four relevant states to consider: we can denote them

$$ \chi_{n,s} (x_i) = \psi_n(x_i) \otimes \binom{s}{1-s} $$

where $\psi_{n=1,2}$ correspond to the spatial wave functions of energy $E_n$ and $s=0,1$ correspond to spin down and up, respectively.

If we now make a Slater determinant for three electrons from e.g. $(n,s)=(1,0), (1,1),(2,1)$ we get

$$ \Psi(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (\psi_1(x_1) \otimes \binom{0}{1})(\psi_1(x_2) \otimes \binom{1}{0})(\psi_2(x_3) \otimes \binom{0}{1}) $$
$$ - (\psi_1(x_1) \otimes \binom{0}{1})(\psi_1(x_3) \otimes \binom{1}{0})(\psi_2(x_2) \otimes \binom{0}{1}) $$
$$- (\psi_1(x_2) \otimes \binom{0}{1})(\psi_1(x_1) \otimes \binom{1}{0})(\psi_2(x_3) \otimes \binom{0}{1}) $$
$$ + (\psi_1(x_2) \otimes \binom{0}{1})(\psi_1(x_3) \otimes \binom{1}{0})(\psi_2(x_1) \otimes \binom{0}{1}) $$
$$ \ldots $$
where I have omitted a normalization coefficient of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3!}}$ in front. Notice that if any coordinates coincide e.g. $x_1 = x_2$ then the whole thing becomes zero, satisfying the overall antisymmetry.